# iOS Xcode 6: 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread'

Tags: ios, concurrency, ios8, xcode6, realm

I'm having some issues with Realm and concurrency. Reading the documentation for Cocoa, it wasn't clear to me that RLMObjects couldn't be shared across threads, so I ran into some thread errors, but now when I try even basic transactions on the default realm, I'm receiving an exception. For example, this is the only controller that I'm using:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

And this is the output:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac83f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a91cbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   Key                                 0x0000000109b0cca1 _Z14RLMCheckThreadP8RLMRealm + 129
3   Key                                 0x0000000109b697bf -[RLMRealm beginWriteTransaction] + 47
4   Key                                 0x0000000109aafbe1 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 177
5   UIKit                               0x000000010b195a90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
6   UIKit                               0x000000010b195c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
7   UIKit                               0x000000010b0b4ca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
```

Has anyone else run into issues with concurrency and Realm? I like the concept, but I might have to switch to FMDB if this continues to be an issue.

Comment: Your code is not using the default Realm; it's creating a new one. Try using [RLMRealm defaultRealm] instead of alloc-initing one.

Comment: @user1447447: Please open a [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) if you have suggestions for improvements to docs or error handling. Thanks!

Comment: @user1447447: are you still having seeing the same issue when using the `defaultRealm`?

Comment: Wonder whether this issue has been checked

Comment: Nothing more annoying than when someone asks a question like this, gets feedback, and leaves everyone else hanging.

Comment: Never received any feedback, had to switch to FMDB. IMO, concurrency with Realm is awkward - if the desired design pattern is something like PONO (plain-old nsobject), then I really don't think that it's been achieved. For me it seemed like many of the annoyances with coredata with none of the benefits.